# Mouse pointer hard to see in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I use OSX and prefer a dark BG and light text in my terminal. A problem is that the mouse pointer is almost invisible. Its the `I` shaped pointer, its black with an extremely faint white glow. I often can't see where the pointer is.

If the terminal does not have focus and I'm hovering the mouse pointer over the terminal window I can see it fine. But once the terminal has focus the pointer practically disappears.

Please note, I'm asking about the mouse pointer not the terminal keyboard cursor, which is easily customisable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Holding down the alt or option key on Mac OSX changes the cursor to a black cross that has a white border which makes it *far* easier to spot than the default text bar.

Comment: This is great. However, is it possible to make that happen whenever my mouse pointer hovers over the terminal rather than whenever I press alt key? or is there any program that does that?

Comment: I would also like to know a solution for this one.

Comment: Isn't this a temporary solution?

Comment: The 'alt' key on a Mac? Do tell, where does one find an Alt key on a Mac?

Answer (score 6):

A better term to look for is "mouse pointer".  Here are some places where it has been discussed:

- [Change default mouse cursor on OSX Mavericks](https://superuser.com/questions/766599/change-default-mouse-cursor-on-osx-mavericks)
- [Can I make the mouse hairpin in the terminal more visible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20112/can-i-make-the-mouse-hairpin-in-the-terminal-more-visible)
- [Terminal app mouse-pointer invisible](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5554351)

More than one solution is suggested, including add-ons (which you may or may not find useful).

Answer (score 2):

Following the links in Thomas Dickey's answer, I saw many references to [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/).

While this won't be the solution for everyone, it's definitely worth a try - GPL2, easy to install and configure.

Out of the box, no contrast issues with the text cursor or mouse pointer against a black background. I just adjusted font size and switched on window borders.

Comment: I would add that as of April 2017 iTerm2 smartly uses `I` cursor which is white on one side and black on the other which makes it visible on both dark and light backgrounds.